# Restore merged user folder

Tags: windows-10, folder-redirection

First I'll start by saying I have no usable backup or restore point (I know, I know).

So the problem, I was using the "Move" function for relocating the default Music folder, I was going from `D:/Music` to `C:/Users/myuser/Music`. I accidentally moved it to `C:/Users/myuser`.

I'm not worried about losing the music itself, I have copies. The problem is that now my user folder cannot be renamed from Music, and the move functionality no longer works, stating `Can't move the folder because there is a folder in the same location that can't be redirected. Access is denied.`

How do I restore my filepath?

Edit:

I've moved the music files and changed the registry key to D:/Music. This has not fixed the `Music` button on the side of Explorer from redirecting to my user profile, but the registry at least is pointing to the correct location

Answer (score 0):

That error was shown because the your user folder was renamed to **Music**. To fix that error, follow these steps:

Rename the new **Music** folder to your user name. Let assume music name is **Andrew**. For example, the renaming will be from **C:\Users\Music** to **C:\Users\Andrew**.

Check if a folder exists as **C:\Users\Andrew\Music**. If that folder doesn't exist, create a Music folder in **C:\Users\Andrew** directory.

Then try to '**Restore Default**' as usual.

We can see the following two articles for further reading.

[How to Restore Default Location of Your Personal Folders in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/23504-restore-default-location-personal-folders-windows-10-a.html)

[Operation to change a personal folder location fails in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2936105/operation-to-change-a-personal-folder-location-fails-in-windows)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't rename `C:/Users/Music`. The option is greyed out, it appears it still thinks that it is the Music library, even though the registry now points to `C:/Users/myuser/Music`

Comment: Also for what it's worth I won't be wanting to move the files when changing the library location, as I've already sorted that manually